# Dot All Regex to Match and Capture Between Two Tokens in a File

Tags: regex, string, dart

I'm writing a regex to to capture all text in a multi line file between `@id=1` and `#`. When I say `#` I mean the first solitary `#` at the start of a line with an optional space afterwards. I'm programming in dart. The regex I came up with is as follows:

```
/^@id ?= ?1$(.*)^# ?$/gms
```

I'm getting some strange results. On [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com/5g209) the regex has a match, but it does not stop at the first `# ?$`. In dart, I get no match at all. Here is my dart code

```
  var matchContents =
      RegExp(r'^@id ?= ?1$(.*)^# ?$', multiLine: true, dotAll: true);
  var testString = '''
      alskdfkldsfjd
      # thekt nect
      @id=2
      akdfjdkf
      adlksfj
      @id=1
      adksfklasdjf // This line should be captured
      asdlkfjdkfj  // And this one
      @id=3        // this one
      dkfjadklfja  // And this one
      # 
      kdsalfjaslkdf
      #
      ''';
  print(matchContents.hasMatch(testString)); // This checks if there is any match (it's currently false)
```

Why isn't this working and how do I fix it?

Comment: You may use this regex in `MULTILINE` mode: `^@id *= *1$[^#]*#`. No need to use `dotall` here since we're using negated character class.

Comment: `.*` is greedy, just use the lazy `.*?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that fixed my problem on RegExr but not in dart.

Comment: It works in Dart. You just declared the stirng with indentations and it turns out **you tested against another string in Dart and online**. If the string is defined like `var testString = "alskdfkldsfjd\n# thekt nect\n@id=2\nakdfjdkf\nadlksfj\n@id=1\nadksfklasdjf // This line should be captured\nasdlkfjdkfj  // And this one\n@id=3        // this one\ndkfjadklfja  // And this one\n#kdsalfjaslkdf\n#";` it works. `print(testString);` and you will see. So, **the only real issue** is the **use of the greedy quantifier**.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well you just taught me something new about multiline strings.

Comment: Always make sure you test against one and the same test, both online and in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `dotall` mode you can leverage negated character class to match across line breaks and simplify your regex.

This regex may work for you in `MULTILINE` mode:

```
^@id *= *1[\r\n]+((?:[^#]*#)+?)(?<=^#)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tlmvcs/4)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^@id *= *1`: From a start of line match `@id=1` allowing optional spaces around `=`
- `[\r\n]+`: Match 1+ newline characters
- `([^#]*)`: Match 0 more characters that are not `#` using negated character class `[^#]`
- `#`: Match a `#`
- `(?<=^#)$`: Stop match when we have `#` all by itself on a separate line

Comment: That almost does what I need but this stops at any `#` even at the end of a line or multiple `#`s in a row. What I need is a regex that stops at a `#` that is at the beginning of a line and completely alone on that line except for an optional space.

Comment: please try my updated answer, which matches a `#` in a separate line.

Comment: As it turns out, the reason why it didn't work in dart is because my string was indented. Thanks, your solution works too.

Comment: jfyi with `dotall` it would be `^@id *= *1[\r\n]+(.*?)^#$` but that will be more inefficient